# Discretization in R

Tags: r

Is anyone aware of a package that implements a supervised learning algorithm for the discretization of continuous variables?

The dprep package contained functions along this line, but the package has been deprecated. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still use the `dprep` package, but you have to install it from source (I just tested and it works well). However, you may well have a look at the [discretization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/discretization/) or [infotheo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infotheo/) packages which provide similar functionalities, e.g. equal interval width, equal frequency intervals, ChiMerge, etc.

Comment: Does this look like it has a similar functionality? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classInt/classInt.pdf

Comment: Thanks chl! The discretization and infotheo packages give me everything I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using infotheo

```
> set.seed(1)
> infotheo::discretize(rnorm(10))
   X
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  1
7  2
8  2
9  2
10 1
```