# Discretization and aliasing in R

Tags: r, alias, discretization

So, I have an array of value from 1 to 100, and I need to make it discrete while applying an alias to each discrete value. For example:

```
  A
 10
 15
 55
 15
 70
```

Now, let's say I want to make it discrete over 2 bins (so that 0-50 is one bin and 51-100 is the other one) and alias these bins with 1 and 2. It should result in:

```
A
1
1
2
1
2
```

Please, notice this is different from the discretize function (contained in entropy or infotheo). That function only counts the number of values for each bin.

My question also is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995662/discretization-in-r) (with a similar title).

Now, I can have this result using a series of ifs, but I was wondering whether exist a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the function `cut`:

```
x <- cut(sample(1:100, 10), c(0, 50, 100))
str(x)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "(0,50]","(50,100]": 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was searching for! More precisely (in case future users have problems with factors as I do) as.numeric(x). :)